# How can I call show dialog using onpressed inside body of build

Tags: flutter

I tried using the following function inside build body.But it throws error saying

```
The argument type 'Future<void> Function(BuildContext)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'
```

```
Future<void> confirmation(BuildContext context) async {
  return await showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
            content: Center( 
               child: Text(
              "Please Wait....",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),
            )));
      });
}


class Trial extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Request Processed')),
        body: Center(
          child: Flatbutton(onPressed: confirmation,child: Text('Click me')), //this onpressed shows error
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried calling the same function from appBar action widget icon and it didn't throw any error.On using in build function only it throws error. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call it like this

```
class Trial extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Request Processed')),
        body: Center(
          child: Flatbutton(onPressed: () {confirmation(context);},child: Text('Click me')), //this onpressed shows error
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It seems the same but it saved me a lot of time. Let me know:)

Comment: That helped.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `context` while calling it. Like this `()=>confirmation(context)`

```dart
class Trial extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Request Processed')),
        body: Center(
          child: Flatbutton(onPressed: ()=>confirmation(context),child: Text('Click me')), //this onpressed shows error
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```